# Add Javascript to jax-rs endpoint

Tags: java, javascript, jax-rs

I need to return an html code from a JAX-RS endpoint. I followed some tutorials and got to know that I can return it as a String. But the problem is I need to add JavaScript function to that returning HTML. How can I do it?

My code snippet.

```
return "<html><body>Hello World</html></body>"
```

Comment: In theory you could include a <script> section in your string, but that just sounds messy :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can add javascript function inside the returning String. You can follow the same steps following when declaring a javascript inside a html page.
I will provide an example:

return "place your script here Hello World"

Make sure to put the script inside  tags.